# cordova Jquery and javascript wont run

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

I am trying to build an app with Cordova. Sadly My javascript wont work for some reason... Can someone help with fixing this?

All i have (for now) in the index.html

```
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *; img-src 'self' data: content:;">
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, width=device-width, viewport-fit=cover">
        <meta name="color-scheme" content="light dark">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <title>Hello World</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="app">
        <h1 id="title">Test</h1>
        <p id="change">The <span class="blink">best</span> app</p>
        <button id="btn">Change content of all p elements</button>
    </div>
    <script src="js/test.js"></script>
    </body>
```

And in the js/test.js:

```
$("#btn").click(function(){
  $("#change").html("<b>Hello world!</b>");
});
```

So there shouldn't be too much that could go wrong, except it does...

Edit: Even normal Javascript wont work?

Comment: @KevinB I have now put the <script src="js/test.js"></script> just above the </body> Sadly this did not fix it.

Comment: Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: @Cybershadow To be honest, I have no idea how to open the console..

Comment: To learn about how to debug cordova apps you can check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45159348/how-to-debug-a-cordova-hybrid-app. TLDR would be -  Go to **chrome://inspect/#devices**

Comment: Thank you! I have now got the following error from the console:

Refused to load the script 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As clarified by the console messages, your Content Security Policy is blocking the external jquery script. You need to allow that external script in your CSP.
To do that you need to change this meta tag

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *; img-src 'self' data: content:;">`
to

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *; img-src 'self' data: content:;script-src https://ajax.googleapis.com">
```

We just added a **script-src** rule to whitelist our jquery script.

To learn more you can check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60758547/how-to-allow-content-security-policy-to-run-external-javascript-from-google-api)